# Recycleview in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with:

> RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

I can't define adapter in `OnCreate` because the list is not ready.

How I can define adapter in `OnCreate`? or what is a possible solution for resolve my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout)

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate I did:

```
  adapter = MyAdapter(this@MyActivity)
  adapter.data = ArrayList()
```

Then later I just set `adapter.date = xxx`

In my adapter I have:

```
class MyAdapter(val activity: MyActivity) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.BodyViewHolder>() {

    var data: MutableList<MyModel>? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    override fun getItemCount() = data?.size ?: 0

    fun ViewGroup.inflate(@LayoutRes layoutRes: Int, attachToRoot: Boolean = false): View {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutRes, this, attachToRoot)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BodyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false)
        return BodyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BodyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindValue(data?.get(position), activity)
    }

    class BodyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bindValue(record: MyModel?, activity: MyActivity) {
            record?.let {
                itemView.mTextView.text = ....
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Worth mentioning that the height of my recycler view is wrap_content

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/mRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's totally ok if you don't have data in `onCreate`. What you need to do is to define the adapter and bind it with your `RecyclerView`. Once you have data ready, add data to the list in `adapter` and notify it. Example as below

```
class MyAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {
    private val data = mutableListOf<MyModel>()

    override fun getItemCount() = data.count()

    fun addData(data : MyModel) {
        // add single data the list or call addAll() to add a group of data. 
        // just remember not to replace the variable
    }

    fun clearData() {

    }

    fun deleteData(id: Int) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class adpCoba(val context: Context, val datalist:ArrayList<dataCoba>):RecyclerView.Adapter<adpCoba.MyViewHolder>(){

    class MyViewHolder (itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val text :TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textcoba)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fetch_coba,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currntItem = datalist [position]
        holder.text.text= currntItem.nama
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return datalist.size
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.